# Excel Median If from two tables

Tags: excel

Hi Please could you share your thoughts on the following:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u5QZ.jpg)

Looking for a formula that could calculate median from two tables for the corresponding values in columns A and F.

e.g. for value 'a' present in cells A1, A4 and F6 this would be median of {0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1,0.6}=0.5

Comment: Your screenshot is pretty much useless, just paste the table content and format it in your question. People are less likely to open links and even less likely to reproduce the tables themselves in order to use them.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep this in mind for future postings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **array formula** for this - see screenshot below

Formula in `B10` is

`=MEDIAN(IF($A$1:$A$6=A10,B$1:D$6),IF(F$1:F$6=A10,G$1:I$6))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down to `B16`

[image]

Comment: The formula works brilliantly but I don’t understand it.
Why range $A$1:$A$6 has fixed address whilst G$1:I$6 are only semi-fixed?

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira Sorry, just me being inconsistent, I only meant to fix sufficiently for copying down, i.e. with row numbers fixed